# Python - how to write a window shared folder path (ex. \\192.168.1.19\cert\testcert.pfx) using pywinrm

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, powershell, winrm

I access to one remote machine to automate some ssl task. To accomplish this from the remote I need import a file from a shared network folder in windows. I´m using pywinrm then after a successful session started I run:

```
s.run_ps('''
    $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force {0}
    Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath {1} -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\WebHosting - 
    Password $Password
    '''.format(secret, path)
```

using similar script with local folder paths I don't have any problem but typing kind of this `\\192.168.1.19\cert\testcert.pfx` I have the following error

```
std_error b'Import-PfxCertificate : The system cannot find the path specified. 0x80070003 \n(WIN32: 3 ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)\nAt line:3 char:9\n+         Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath \\192.168.1.19\\Certificates1\\test ...\n+
```

I built this path like string `"host"+"\\"+cert+"\\"+file` where `host = "\\192.168.1.19", cert = "Certificates1", and file = "testcert.pfx"`

I have seen that in powershell I should type exactly `PS C:\>\\192.168.1.19\cert\testcert.pfx` and it works but pointing to the error the string that is passing python to powershell is \ and not escaping and passing only one backslash.

Any help or advice?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `//192.168.1.19/cert/testcert.pfx`?

Comment: In powershell and my script this option don´t work

Comment: The error suggests you need to use single backslashes between the path segments `"host"+"\"+cert+"\"+file`. The only double backslash is in front of the host (name or IP)

Comment: @Theo this raise error :v but if put raw string python by default put one more backslash in the final string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem deals with the second hop issue, so the script can't access to another network shared file while remoting.
The solution was change authentication to CredSSP and allowing the second hop delegate the credentials.
After this, no errors referring to any path appears.